# Activate SNI for C# SOAP Service

Tags: c#, ssl, soap, service, sni

I'm providing a SOAP service with C# as a service. So far, everything has always worked without problems. But now someone wants to use this service, and he absolutely needs the support of SNI.

Here is my app.config:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="OurServiceBehavior">
          <serviceCredentials>
            <clientCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="None"/>
            </clientCertificate>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint"/>
          </serviceCredentials>
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="OurServiceBehavior" name="myservice.myservice">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="https://example.de:1234/MyService"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SecureBinding" bindingNamespace="https://example.de:1234/MyService" contract="myservice.myservice"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>

    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="SecureBinding" closeTimeout="00:010:00" openTimeout="00:010:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:010:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false"/>
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

  </system.serviceModel>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6"/></startup></configuration>
```

Do you know how to activate SNI?

Comment: SNI based bindings are at HTTP.sys level, which typically you configure via `netsh http` command. Do a Google search and you should find out. https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/https-binding.html#sni-based-bindings

Comment: I'm not running an IIS Server. Can't find a possibility to activate SNI for http.sys

Comment: HTTP.sys is part of Windows. So whether you use IIS or not you have to go through it. In your case, use `netsh http add sslcert` with a proper `hostnameport` mapping should work, https://balofg.wordpress.com/2015/07/09/netsh-add-sslcert-by-hostname/

Comment: @LexLi Thanks alot, SNI is now activated! Thank you a thousand times.